# RabbitMQ cluster on EC2 without Route 53

Tags: amazon-ec2, rabbitmq

I’m trying to set up a clustered deployment of RabbitMQ in a VPC in EC2 based on the documentation here (https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html) and here (https://www.rabbitmq.com/ec2.html)

We currently don't have Route 53 set up within our VPC and rely on the private IP addresses for connections between instances.

I've been trying to get the cluster working without setting up Route 53 by using the private IP address as the hostname as follows:

(Assuming private IP address is 10.0.1.33)

- Alter /etc/hostname changing

  ip-10-0-1-33

  to

  10.0.1.33
- Alter /etc/hosts changing

  127.0.0.1   localhost

  to

  127.0.0.1   localhost 10.0.1.33
- Change hostname ie `sudo hostname 10.0.1.33` (or reboot instance to pick up new hostname)
- Add file rabbitmq-env.conf to /etc/rabbitmq with contents:

  USE_LONGNAME=true

This seems to work and allow me to cluster the rabbit nodes using rabbitmqctl since rabbit treats the private IP address as a fully qualified domain name (USE_LONGNAME is necessary or else rabbit just uses the part of the IP address before the first dot) and the IP addresses are resolvable in the VPC - I get the nodes named rabbit@10.0.1.33 etc

My question is - is there anything I'm missing here or is this a reasonable approach?

Comment: I'm also looking to get clustering working on an EC2 Auto Scaling Group without using Route 53.  It sounds like what you have works - have you noticed any problems at all?  IMO, if it ain't broke, don't fix it.  Thanks for posting your setup